# Integrate menu from jQuery filtering plugin (Filtrify) into site menu

Tags: jquery-plugins, filter, tags

I need to create a way for users to parse db query results by multiple tags from different categories, and displays a legend with the number of matches next to the related menu item *(similar to the navigation + filtering that is used on shopstyle.com and many retail sites)*.

The jQuery plugin [Filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.com/filtrify/) seems like an easy way to dynamically filter items by search criteria however it dynamically generates it's own distinct menu, and I need to integrate the filtering capability into a website's existing menu and search options. 
Filtrify creates a search menu with field labels for each of the categories (HTML5 `data attributes`) that have been assigned to items in the 'containerID', and each field label in the menu fires a "popup" filtering panel. Filtrify's menu is called in its entirety wherever the 'placeHolderID' is located.

I'm trying to figure out how to call specific categories instead of the entire menu so that I can incorporate it into the relevant section of the menu and apply the necessary formatting? Alternatively, I'd be open to another method or plugin that would allow me to do this.

The script for the Filtrify plugin is available [here](https://github.com/luis-almeida/filtrify/blob/master/js/filtrify.js), and I've included below the code used to apply the plugin to my document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.filtrify("containerID", "placeHolderID");
    });
</script>    

<div id="placeHolderID" style="display:none"></div>

<ul id="containerID">
<li data-item="Dresses" data-style="Long Sleeves, V-Neck" data-price="$300 - $400" data-color="Black">
<!-- Product Fields -->
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Chaya... it seems we get in touch again on very similar issue. I'm also working with filtrify in these days.
I don't understand if you want to visualize only some categories (i.e.  only some 'data-xxxx' tags) or a limited number of entries in each categories.

In any case I'm also having a problem, but I'll tell you after you anser to my comment.

Comment: Hi @DanieleB :-D Love that we're reconnecting about this now that I've finally had a chance to play around with Filtrify some more ;-) I know that you can limit which categories are displayed in the menu, but I haven't been able to figure out how to split up the categories so that it can be incorporated into an existing menu (with each category being displayed in different locations). It would be awesome to figure this out because otherwise I'll have to give up on Filtrify and code it all myself

Comment: no time now to give you a full solution. But you should override the Filtrify.prototype.build = function ( f ) at line 112 of filtrify.js. Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/79KxJ/

Comment: @DanieleB - I combined your fiddle with a very basic menu http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/79KxJ/1/ and have been playing around with the 'prototype.build' function for the past few hours, but I'm not really proficient enough in js to figure out how to modify it :-( Any chance that you'd be able to show me how to do it?

Comment: I'll work on that a bit on Monday. In any case, the idea is the following: the prototype.build function creates a new pop-up with the list. The job to be done is to rewrite the function so that it does not create a pop-up but appends the list of entries/items to the menus you have (in the jsfiddle example you provided they are the 'GenreActors DirectorAccount InfoAbout Us'...
See you on Monday :-D

Comment: You're awesome :-D I think that the best way to do it would be to generate variables for each data-attribute's menu, and ideally have a way to control the individual values since the values are often a part of a sub-menu or search tool (i.e. a color chart)

Comment: it seems very complex... Are you sure that using the filtrify plugin is the best way to do it?

Maybe there are other efficient ways, as the use of [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) if you have to perform complex actions on a list of items. I used it on my site http://epos-couch.cloudant.com/epos-couch/_design/epos-couch/index.html